# PostgreSQL query optimization challenge

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I am trying to optimize this query:

```
SELECT eq.*,
    reg_last_dt.dt as reg_last_date
FROM Equipment eq
  INNER JOIN (
    select max( dt ) as dt, id_eq_equipment 
    from consum 
    group by id_eq_equipment
  ) as reg_last_dt ON reg_last_dt.id_eq_equipment = eq.id_eq
```

Explain shows me this:

```
Hash Join  (cost=839806.69..839833.33 rows=23 width=1461)
  Hash Cond: (eq.id_eq = consum.id_eq_equipment)
  ->  Seq Scan on equipment eq  (cost=0.00..26.29 rows=129 width=1453)
  ->  Hash  (cost=839806.40..839806.40 rows=23 width=10)
        ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=839805.60..839806.17 rows=23 width=10)
              Group Key: consum.id_eq_equipment
              ->  Sort  (cost=839805.60..839805.71 rows=46 width=10)
                    Sort Key: consum.id_eq_equipment
                    ->  Gather  (cost=839799.50..839804.33 rows=46 width=10)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=838799.50..838799.73 rows=23 width=10)
                                Group Key: consum.id_eq_equipment
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on consum  (cost=0.00..755192.33 rows=16721433 width=10)
```

This looks not very optimal. Is there anything I could do to make it better?

Comment: Please follow instructions for performance question here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info

Answer (score 0):

The row estimates in the query plan (only `rows=129` for `Equipment`, and only `rows=23` for aggregated `consum`) indicate that this query using a `LATERAL` subquery instead should perform ***much*** faster:

```sql
SELECT eq.*, r.reg_last_date
FROM   Equipment eq
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT max(dt) AS reg_last_date
   FROM   consum c
   WHERE  c.id_eq_equipment = eq.id_eq
   ) r;
```

Be sure to have a multicolumn **index** on `consum(id_eq_equipment, dt)`!

Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Maybe your really want a `LEFT JOIN` to return all rows from `Equipment`? See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Answer (score 0):

If the estimates in the plan are correct, it would almost certainly be faster to do it with a subselect, this way:

```
SELECT 
    eq.*, 
    (select max( dt ) from consum where consum.id_eq_equipment = eq.id_eq) as reg_last_date
FROM Equipment eq
```

Note this will return NULL for reg_last_date where there is no corresponding record in consum, so you might want to filter those out if you don't want to see them.

You would need an index on `(id_eq_equipment, dt)` to make it fast